# VirtualBox OpenSolaris guest on OS X host; Audio does not work

Tags: macos, virtualbox, opensolaris

I have OpenSolaris 2009.06 installed as a guest operating system on Virtualbox 3.0.4 under OS X 10.5.8.  The VirtualBox guest additions have been installed.  All available updates have been applied to both operating systems and VirtualBox.

The audio does not work.  No sound heard on boot, the volume control in not active, and I get a "Could not open resource for wrtitng" error when I try to play a sample sound from the sound preferences diaglog.

The VirtualBox audio settings are

```
Host Driver: CoreAudio
Controller: ICH AC97
```

Comment: We need details for your "Sound" settings under the VM's settings pane.

Comment: that's usable under OpenSolaris. See my answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot the OpenSolaris guest, and add a new driver binding entry:

> $ pfexec bash
>
> # update_drv -a -i '"pci8086,2415"' audio810

Now the mixerctl command should be able to find sound hardware, and when you restart the gnome desktop the gnome volume control applet should see the audio hardware, too.

Solution taken from [here](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=13851&sid=eb8df2963847e9e54715f3fcf7545e0f).